# How best to let a user redefine a class method?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a library with a completely general implementation with the exception of a single class `A`. This class only has a single function `int format(int i){}` but can't be used as is: `format` depends on each different application and needs to be user-defined. In particular, `format` has quite a few if-then statements that need to be set correctly for the environment of the application. However the rest of the library is completely general, and will work with any choice of `format` that is within certain specifications.

The Question: What's the best way to let the user of my library define how `format` works? This needs to be done on the code level (as opposed to just using a configuration file).

The obvious idea would be to have the user directly rewrite the definition of `format` directly on the source code, but that doesn't sound like the most elegant way to do this.

Another idea would be to use inheritance: Have the user define a `userA` class inheriting from `A` and then hide the `format` function. But the rest of the library uses class `A` instead of `userA`. At this point, it could be possible to replace all instances of `A` with a typename `desiredA` and then have the user define that typename to be `userA`. This is not very elegant either.

There must be a better way to do this right?

Comment: There are several ways to do this and it would depend on the specifics which one might be better. There are tradeoffs.

Comment: You should be a little more specific about what type of changes you're looking for them to be able to make. You just talking data types, or whole sale changes to the structure of the library?

Comment: @Andrew The signature of the function will always be the same, but the implementation will be different. No other changes will happen with the library

Comment: Have you considered using function templates?

https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/templates 

Seems like this will achieve what you're looking for if implemented properly.

Comment: How drastically does the implementation of `format` change? Are we talking something like a few numeric parameters, or something more drastic like no code shared between applications other than the function signature? Is there a limit on the number of possible implementations, or is it more like no two applications will ever use the same version of `format`?

Comment: @Andrew Yes but this would still rely on a typedef at the end. It's also possible to do this with the curiously recurring pattern.

Comment: @JaMiT  ```format``` does not share any code with other applications (it's completely self contained), however it would be very complicated to write a (very) general version of ```format``` and then have certain variables change. Possible, but complicated.

Comment: @user12005284 Hmm... in that case asking each application to supply the function (as done in the accepted answer) would be my choice of approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that I have used in the past.

1. Add the ability to let the user to register a function of their choosing.
2. If a user defined function has been registered, call it. Otherwise, use some default function.

```
using UserFunctionType = int(*)(int i);
UserFunctionType registeredFunction = nullptr;
void registerUserFunction(UserFunctionType f) { registeredFunction = f; }

int format(int i)
{
   if ( registeredFunction ) 
   {
      return registeredFunction(i);
   }
   else
   {
      // Some default implementation
   }
}
```

---

User code would be something like:

```
int myFunction(int i)
{
   // Return whatever makes sense.
}

int my_init()
{
   registerUserFunction(myFunction);
   return 0;
}

// Make sure my_init() gets called at program startup time.
static int dummy = my_init();
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to how the user would be able to input their function. Do they make a new header+cpp file and then include that in my library? Or do I just have an empty cpp file where they can implement their function? Isn't that just the same as letting them modify the source code for format directly?

Comment: @user12005284, They have to 1) Define a function and 2) Register the function. It's better because you can give your code as a library to the user. They won't have to modify your code.

Comment: Right but the registering needs to happen in a file the rest of the library can see. How does that work?

Comment: @user12005284, no, that is not necessary. That's how callback functions work.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I was confused. This makes sense yes.

Comment: I'm going to wait to see if there are any other answers coming in and if not, then accept it. Thanks!